# Unable to get reasonably formatted JSON response from Mediawiki API

Tags: mediawiki

While logged on to my wiki, one of my Javascripts on a Wikipage does the following:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url = "/wiki4/api.php";

var params = {action: "purge", titles: title, format: "json"};

xhr.open ('POST', url, true);                                               

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify( params ));
```

I get back HTML (instead of json) and the contents is the Mediawiki Api help.

I was actually expecting a JSON formatted response tailored to my request.

When I do this with a GET request and URL-encoded parameters, I get the expected JSON formatted response (which is an error message informing me that I should use a POST request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params should be in the request URL as query strings, and not in the request body.

See [documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiHelp/purge) to learn more.

Comment: Oddly enough, this works. Oddly, since a POST with parameters in the query string instead of the body is uncommon, though formally correct. A **second  solution** is to keep the parameters in the POST body but send a FormData element in the body with a Content.Disposition:form-data header. Looks like the API does not support JSON. The documentation does not help: The example link given there suggests a GET *and* is *implemented* on the page as a GET; it leads to an error as well.